# identifying strings within intervals, pt 1

Tags: awk, sed

I would like to know if column 3 is within column 1 and 2 by indicating "yes" or "no" in column 4 for each row. Is this doable in awk?

### Input

```
start end snp-pos region
392   508 410     
100   216 222 
269   388 198
```

### Desired output

```
start  end  snp-pos  region
392    508  410      yes
100    216  222      no
269    388  198      no
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==1{print;next} {print $0, ($3>$1 && $3<$2 ? "yes" : "no")}' file
start end snp-pos region
392   508 410 yes
100   216 222 no
269   388 198 no
```

If you care about the columns lining up you can pipe to `column -t`:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{print;next} {print $0, ($3>$1 && $3<$2 ? "yes" : "no")}' file | column -t
start  end  snp-pos  region
392    508  410      yes
100    216  222      no
269    388  198      no
```

or we can write slightly more code and deal with it entirely within awk, e.g.:

```
awk 'NR==1{print;w=match($0,$NF)-1;next} {printf "%-*s%s\n", w, $0, ($3>$1 && $3<$2 ? "yes" : "no")}' file
start end snp-pos region
392   508 410     yes
100   216 222     no
269   388 198     no
```

Comment: I updated my answer. You didn't specify any cases where $2 is exactly the same value as $1 or $3 or any other unusual cases so you'll need to massage to suit.